# How can I create realistic business card mockups?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, presentation-design, mockup

I'm trying to produce the effect in the below image:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/3t1waszx5/]

I'd preferably like to do this with Photoshop or Illustrator. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a canonical answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/113783/41100

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quick and easy solution is using a PSD mock-up template. There are a lot of options available on [**Pixeden**](http://www.pixeden.com/), such as this free one: [**Psd Business Card Mock-Up Vol 1**](http://www.pixeden.com/psd-mock-up-templates/psd-business-card-mock-up-vol-1)

I made this in Photoshop using that template:

[image: Fake Business Card]

Here is one that is available for purchase that is a little closer to the one you linked: [**Psd Business Card Mockup Vol7**](http://www.pixeden.com/psd-mock-up-templates/psd-business-card-mockup-vol7)